# If A subtends B, can B also subtend A?

Tags: word-usage, mathematics

I wrote:

> Things farther away subtend smaller angles at the eye.

Wiktionary has [this example](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtend) of the usage of "subtend:"

> A 43° angle subtends an arc about ¾ meter long on a circle with a radius of 1 meter.

Can we say both that an angle subtends an arc and that the arc subtends the angle, or is my usage wrong?

The etymology is "stretch under," and "under" doesn't seem to imply any such distinction in a general context like this, where our geometrical figure has no particular orientation with respect to the earth.

As a side note, are there examples of correct usage where A subtends B, and neither A nor B is an angle? As a trivial example, I suppose we could have a solid angle rather than a plane angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/subtend), subtend is a geometrical term. If A subtends B, A could be a line, arc, segment, or other geometrical figure. B is usually an an angle.

But a chord/angle can also subtend an line/arc.

> (Of an angle or chord) have bounding lines or points that meet or coincide with those of (a line or arc).
>
> *...bounded by an arc of the circle and the chord subtending it*.

There's another use case in botany:

> *Botany* (Of a bract) extend under (a flower) so as to support or enfold it:
>
> *the main beauty is provided by the bracts which subtend the flowers*

Comment: The oxforddictionaries entry has 1 and 1.1, which seem to be basically a line subtending an angle and an angle subtending a line, so this supports your first two paragraphs. But later you have this: "However, I don't think B can subtend A in either case. An line can't subtend a chord. An angle can't subtend a line." This seems to contradict what you said earlier, and I don't see anything in the oxforddictionaries entry to support it.

Comment: @BenCrowell: A line can't subtend(1.1) a chord. An angle can't subtend(1) a line. That's what I meant. But I see your point.

Comment: *A line can't subtend(1.1) a chord. An angle can't subtend(1) a line.* Is this based on taking the lists given in parentheses in the definitions, and taking them to be exhaustive? That interpretation doesn't seem right to me. For example, an area on the surface of a sphere can clearly subtend a solid angle, but those things aren't on the lists in the definition.

Comment: @BenCrowell: Edited out the controversial part. Maybe I'm wrong about that.